# WPF InstallShield installer giving error

Tags: wpf, prism, installshield

I have WPF app.In debug mode and release mode it works fine.Also, Im able to  create installer using InstallShield (integrated in visual studio 2015).

But, after installing in machine, it gives me error :

```
   Application: PerfectSmile.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveAssembly(BamlAssembly)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlTypeToType(BamlType)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType, Int16)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_BamlRecords()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Read()
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack`1<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame>, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at PerfectSmile.Views.Shell.InitializeComponent()
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext+<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride>)

Exception Info: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride>)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type, System.String, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at PerfectSmile.Common.BootStrapper.CreateShell()
   at Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean)
   at PerfectSmile.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at PerfectSmile.App.Main()
```

Can anyone assist me ?

Regards,
Pawan

Comment: You'll probably have to help yourself. The FileNotFoundException seems to indicate that something required isn't available. You may have to install this file, or a redist that contains it, etc.

Comment: Thakns for reply! I feel, My app first break due to  Exception Info: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException....Any idea how to resolve this prism error ?